# How to use react-native multiple checkbox and get the selected Id

Tags: react-native, checkbox

i have used react-native-select-multiple. but not working, How do i use multiple checkbox in react native and get the select multiple id and pass to next page..?

Answer (score 0):

this is how to use the library, get selected items, pass the items selected and get the items on the next page.

```js
const fruits = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'banana']


this.state = {
  selectedFruits: [],
}

onSelectionsChange = (selectedFruits) => {
    // selectedFruits is array of { label, value }
    this.setState({
      selectedFruits
    })
  }

  <
  SelectMultiple
items = {
  fruits
}
rowStyle = {
  {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  }
}
labelStyle = {
  {
    color: 'white'
  }
}
checkboxStyle = {
  {
    borderColor: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
}
style = {
  {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
    width: setWidth,
    height: setHeight
  }
}
selectedItems = {
  this.state.selectedFruits
}
onSelectionsChange = {
  this.onSelectionsChange
}
/>

navigate('Screen', {
      fruits: this.state.selectedFruits
    } //using react-navigation. or Actions.Screen({fruits: this.state.selectedFruits})//using react-native-router-flux

    this.props.navigation.state.params.fruits //using react-navigation or this.props.fruits//using react-native-router-flux
```

Comment: when i pass the value to next screen there is an error
"undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.selectedFruits')"

Comment: <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.nextScreen({fruits:this.state.selectedFruits})}>
 
<Text>next</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>

there is an error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.selectedFruits')"

Comment: can you log your output, to get it in the next screen, you need to use-- this.props.fruits